# popup is shown blank on Internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to show a popup on for printing a page.
    But the popup is shown blank on the internet explorer.
    Can anyone tell me how to show its contents on the IE. Following is my code-

```
     <script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <SCRIPT Language="Javascript"><!-- Begin




            function printit(){  
                if (window.print) {
                     window.print() ;


                } else {

                    var WebBrowser = '<OBJECT ID="WebBrowser1" WIDTH=0 HEIGHT=0 CLASSID="CLSID:8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-00C04FD705A2"></OBJECT>';
                    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeEnd', WebBrowser);

                   WebBrowser1.ExecWB(6, 2);//Use a 1 vs. a 2 for a prompting dialog box    WebBrowser1.outerHTML = "";  
                }}

                var NS = (navigator.appName == "Netscape");
                var VERSION = parseInt(navigator.appVersion);
                if (VERSION > 3 )
                {
                    document.open();
                    document.write('<table><tr><form><td>&nbsp;&nbsp;');
                    document.write('<input type=button value=" Print this page " name="Print" onClick="printit()" class=tbflat style="cursor:hand;">');
                    document.write('</td></form></tr></table><br>');        
                    document.write('<img class="logo" src="/v/vspfiles/assets/images/logo.jpg" />');
                    document.close();

                }


            //  End --></script>

Please advise.
```

Comment: That code has blown my mind.

Comment: You're saying this code works for other browsers??? This snippet is placed in the pop-up? If so, heavily misused [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write)  is causing troubles here.

Comment: What ancient version of IE didn't have `window.print`?